# How do I disable Preview Icon using objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macos

How do I disable the "Show icon preview" checkbox in Finder using objective-c (see screenshot). I want to disable it for specific folders, not system wide.

[image]

Comment: By the way, you can rid of the border around your window by typing the space bar _after_ pressing ⇧⌘4, then clicking on the window of interest. The resulting screenshot is clean and doesn't need cropping. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use AppleScript through [`NSAppleScript`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAppleScript_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSAppleScript):

```
tell application "Finder"
    -- create a new finder window
    set newWindow to make new Finder window

    -- Alternatively you could use
    -- set target of newWindow to folder "Macintosh HD:SomeFolder"
    set target of newWindow to choose folder

    -- get the options of that new window
    set options to icon view options of newWindow

    -- disable preview
    set shows icon preview of options to false
    close newWindow
end tell
```

I believe this information is stored in the .DS_Store files, but still the only save way of modifying it is through the Finder.